# SharePoint Subsite - Iterate over lists

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint site. I am trying to open a subsite and get a list of all lists in that subsite. This code returns the top level "http://myspserver" lists.
How do I get only the lists from /mysubsite?

```
string webUrl = "http://myspserver/mysubsite";

using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite(webUrl).OpenWeb()) //Open SP Web
{

    SPListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists; //Open Lists

    foreach (SPList oList in SPContext.Current.Web.Lists)
    //For Each List Execute this
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should iterate over `collList`, not `SPContext.Current.Web.Lists`.

```
foreach (SPList oList in collList)
{
}
```

`SPContext.Current.Web.Lists` will get the site you are currently in. Presumably, this is `http://myspserver` when you run your code.

Also, note that your code leaks - you do not dispose of the SPSite object. It should look like:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
using(SPWeb oWebsite = site.OpenWeb())
{
}
```

Comment: I am still trying to understand the concept of memory leaks is there any information you can give me to try and help me understand leaks.

Comment: @josephs8 - I'll get back to you tomorrow, but it should be easy to find a good resource.

Comment: Disposing is more concerned about freeing unmanaged resources (which in some cases can be a far more finite resource) and not so much about managed memory.

Answer (score 2):

You create the `SPListCollection` object, but there you use the `SPContext.Current.Web.Lists` in your `foreach`, correct your code like this and things should be fine:

```
string webUrl = "http://myspserver/mysubsite";

using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite(webUrl).OpenWeb()) //Open SP Web
{

    SPListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists; //Open Lists

    foreach (SPList oList in collList)
    //For Each List Execute this
    {
       ....
    }
}
```